# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\tempFolder" "read") on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I am migrating my application from Tomcat to Google App Engine (1.9.1). I am running jsf 2.2 on servlet 2.5 and I am facing an issue with reading files from file system. I have code that creates a file on the file system as follows:

```
File file = new File("C:\\tempFolder");
if(file.isDirectory()){
  // do writing stuff here
}
```

On Tomcat I was not getting any exceptions on the above code, but on Google App Engine I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\tempFolder" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
```

Why am I getting this exception, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why i am getting this exception

GAE environment is sandboxed for a number of reasons. This means that you cannot do a lot of things you could normally do on your local machine.

This also includes write access to the file system.

> how to fix it

Find another way to persist your data (database, for example).

You can read a little bit more on sandbox restrictions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox).

Comment: do you have any idea about the common way used to upload files with jsf on GAE ?

Comment: this issue happens when i am trying to upload file to server

Comment: @MahmoudS Nope, have not dealt with file uploads in GAE.